# push xml values in to an array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the XML file,

```
<root>
<items>
 <webprotal-gallery>
  <web-portal-urls>http://xxx.xom/image</web-portal-urls>
  <web-portal-urls>http://xxx.xom/image</web-portal-urls>
  <-----   -----------    ---------------   ------------>
 </webprotal-gallery> 
</items>
<items>
<webprotal-gallery>
  <web-portal-urls>http://xxx.xom/image</web-portal-urls>
  <web-portal-urls>http://xxx.xom/image</web-portal-urls>     
 </webprotal-gallery>
</items>
</root>
```

I want to push 'web-portal-urls' in to an associative array(key/value).
My requrement is, When the user clicks on image, to show assosiative 'webprotal-gallery' in another page.

How to push gallery items in to an array.

Comment: Show your code that you tried..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function parseXml(xml){
    var xmlDoc, parser;

    if (window.DOMParser){
        parser=new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");
    } else {
        xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async=false;
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xml); 
    }

    return xmlDoc;
}

var xml = '<root><items><webprotal-gallery><web-portal-urls>http://xxx.xom/image</web-portal-urls><web-portal-urls>http://xxx.xom/image</web-portal-urls></webprotal-gallery></items><items><webprotal-gallery><web-portal-urls>http://xxx.xom/image</web-portal-urls><web-portal-urls>http://xxx.xom/image</web-portal-urls></webprotal-gallery></items></root>';

var xmlDoc = parseXml(xml);
var urls = [];
var tags = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('web-portal-urls');

for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){
    urls.push(tags[i].textContent)
}

console.log(urls)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DFVt2/)

Comment: hi, thank u for u r reply, But i need output like this, gallery1{"image1","image2"},gallery2{"image1","image2"}... so that when the user clicks on the image, i can show all the gallery items to that image